# spring batch - how to pass dynamic list while application running to ListItemReader store it into database

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-batch, spring-data-jpa, c3p0

I'm new to this Spring-Batch technology please help regarding how to pass dynamic list while application running to ListItemReader and store it to MySql DB.

Ex. I fetch some value from DB and do some calculation on that fetched data and i prepare one list and this new list to be pass to ListItemReader and store it into DB.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Below are custom implementations of ListItemWriter and ListItemReader which lets you define a `name` property. This property is used as a key to store the list in the `JobExecutionContext`.

In your case, you can have 3 steps :

1. JDBCReader > ListItemWriter
2. Calculation Tasklet
3. ListItemReader > JDBCWriter

If your tasklet needs to get the lists, you can use the same way as below (ie. read/write the `JobExecutionContext`).

The reader :

```
public class CustomListItemReader<T> implements ItemReader<T>, StepExecutionListener {

    private String name;
    private List<T> list;

    @Override
    public T read() throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException, ParseException, NonTransientResourceException {

        if (list != null && !list.isEmpty()) {
            return list.remove(0);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        list = (List<T>) stepExecution.getJobExecution().getExecutionContext().get(name);
    }

    @Override
    public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        return null;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {  
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

The writer :

```
public class CustomListItemWriter<T> implements ItemWriter<T>, StepExecutionListener {

    private String name;
    private List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends T> items) throws Exception {
        for (T item : items) {
            list.add(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {}

    @Override
    public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        stepExecution.getJobExecution().getExecutionContext().put(name, list);
        return null;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {  
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'll try this solution and let you know the result, and one more thing i want to know is, should i define these classes in spring configuration xml file?

Comment: @AmitKammar No, you don't need to declare these classes in Spring.

Comment: then how to launch this job?

Comment: @AmitKammar You can launch this job like any other Job (with a `JobLauncher` or a `CommandLineJobRunner`). The code in the post is simply 2 classes to add to your project, which you will then call in your `module-context.xml` as reader or writer in your steps.